# Download a PDF file from the server to client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to do is that look up the shared folder from server, and find a file in the directories and download it to my client desktop.

It works just fine downloading from server to my VM desktop, however, it does not download to my client desktop. It just throws an error message saying that the destination path access denied. Not sure why, because when i try it from my VM running as local it works just fine. But if I deploy to our dev server then it throws that error message and does not download to my client desktop.

I've researched and found out that due to the security issue, it will never download to the client desktop, but is there a way to download from server to client desktop?

#1. After finding out the file I want, get it from the server

```
if (!File.Exists(thisFile))
{
     string serverSourcePath = Path.Combine(finalResourcePath + thisFile + ".pdf");

     //What I'm trying to do here is that since the client desktop path starts with C:\\Users\MyCredentials\Desktop\... just get the credentials from the user
     string userName = User.Identity.Name.Replace("CompanyName\\", "");

     string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\Desktop\" + 
     thisFile + ".pdf");

    using (var client = new WebClient() { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
    {    
     try
      {
       client.DownloadFile(serverSourcePath, destinationFilePath);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      return BadRequest(ex.InnerException.Message);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You said, that you deployed to a server? If you are on Windows and IIS or on Linux and kestrel the User which runs the webapplication needs permission to write to the destination folder.

Comment: So I gave all the users who are trying to download a file from the shared folder a full control. As long as he/she is under our domain and using the windows credentials. What permission(s) do I have to grant?

Answer (score 0):

Before downloading, can you try to pull the file to a folder in the application directory and then download it to the desktop?

Comment: Like out of the root of the shared directory?

Comment: Ah you mean like move them to the wwwroot folder?

Comment: yes, put it in a temp folder and download it from there.